# Google maps API, js undefined object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
var myloc;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };    
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
            mapOptions);

  var mylocOptions = {
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: "You are here..."
  };
  myloc = new google.maps.Marker(mylocOptions);

<% if !signed_in? || !current_user.loc %>
  if (navigator.geolocation) navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    var me = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
    myloc.setPosition(me);
    myloc.setMap(map);
    map.setCenter(me);
    $.ajax({
      data: { me: me.toString() },
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/set-location'
    })
  }, function(error) {
      var address = prompt('Where are you looking?');
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var me = results[0].geometry.location
          myloc.setPosition(me);
          myloc.setMap(map);
          map.setCenter(me);
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        };
      });
  });

<% else %>
  var me = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= current_user.loc %>);
  myloc.setPosition(me);
  myloc.setMap(map);
  map.setCenter(me);

<% end %>

}
```

So, I'm not trying to alert stuff, but that's how I found the problem.  When true, `myloc is undefined`.  When false, it's `myloc = Object object`.  Is there something in that `navigator.geolocation` function that allows `myloc` to be recognized?

I thought by declaring `var myloc` outside of the initialize function, everything was gravy.  Scope issue?  Google maps trickery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geolocating is an asynchronous process.

At the time when the callback of `getCurrentPosition` is executed, the marker has already been created, because the browser will continue executing the script while he requests the user-position.

Comment: Google maps trickery it is.  Ideas for implementation, or do I have to ajax something?  Or will it just not work?

Comment: I assume you like to create a marker either based on `current_user.loc` or the geolocation-result? When my assumption is correct, create the marker either inside the if-statement or inside the callback of `getCurrentPosition()`

Comment: as far as I know, I have to create the marker after I create the map... so I don't think I know what you mean.  it creates fine inside of the `getCurrentPosition()` if statement.  the callback for that function is the error, and I have a bunch of stuff in there to let the user type in a search to determine their location.  So, again, not sure I know what you mean.

Comment: Which error? alerting an undefined object is no error, alerting a defined object is no error, and when there some error occurs inside the callback of getCurrentPosition you should show a little bit more of the problematic code than **`~stuff~`** . Additionally: you can create a Marker without creating a map, this must not result in an error. The only thing that may produce an error in the provided code so far is the creation of the marker and map, because your code doesn't contain a variable `mylocOptions` or `mapOptions`

Comment: no problems there, what I'm saying is that the callback is an error... maybe I'm thinking wrong.  I updated the code to show it all.

Comment: the error occurs not in the callback of `getCurrentPosition()`, it happens in the else-statement, because you access there `map` and `myloc`, which are not defined. Move everything after `<% end %>` to the top of the function, before the `<% if !signed_in? || !current_user.loc %>`

Comment: you got it!  just had to move the map creation and marker creation above the location finding.  had to tweak the code for creating the `me` element when logged in.  updated my code...